# How to select as xml from discrete varchar elements?

Tags: xml, sql-server-2012

I have an old SQL Server table that has a `varchar(2056)` column where each row contains discreet "elements" of XML. Is there a way to select these into real XML, using T-SQL?

This will give you an idea of what I am dealing with:

```
declare @xmlTable table(
    Value varchar(2056)
)

insert into @xmlTable 
values ( '<Root>' ),
       ( '  <Child id="1">' ),
       ( '    <Name>Sam</Name>' ),
       ( '  </Child>' ),
       ( '  <Child />' ),
       ( '</Root>' )
```

The problem is that each element is on its own row in the table, and open/close tags can be several rows apart. I've tried converting to XML but, since each row is not valid xml, this fails. I have also tried the old "[select column to CSV using for XML](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/11/25/sql-server-comma-separated-values-csv-from-table-column/)" trick (to create a string I could cast), but that converts my ">" to "& gt ;" etc.

I'm using SQL Server 2012, and this particular table has over 650k rows spread across 560 "documents". I want to be able to say something like:

```
select Value
from @xmlTable
for xml path( '' ), type
```

and return nice chunks of queryable XML.

Thanks!

Comment: Whoops! I'm using sql 2012, NOT 2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
declare @xmlTable table(
    Value varchar(2056)
)

insert into @xmlTable 
values ( '<Root>' ),
       ( '  <Child id="1">' ),
       ( '    <Name>Sam</Name>' ),
       ( '  </Child>' ),
       ( '  <Child />' ),
       ( '</Root>' );

SELECT CAST
(
    (
    SELECT Value AS [*] 
    FROM @xmlTable 
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
    ).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
AS XML);
```

Your problem with the string and the contained escape entities is solved by using `,TYPE` and after this the `value()`-method. Doing so, all escaped characters get re-escaped implicitly.

Comment: Yes this works! At least on the sample data, I'll try it on the big data soon. The big data is all CDATA[] stuff, hopefully that won't cause an issue. I have never seen "as [*]". What exactly is that doing?

Comment: @emery.noel 1) `CDATA`-sections won't disturb, but will be translated into *normally escaped sections*. This shouldn't make a difference... 2) `as [*]` is one of many ways to enforce an unnamed column. Otherwise the generated XML would include named elements 3) Thx for the acceptance! Just one tiny hint: If you like this, you might additionally vote on the answer. Voting and accepting are two different steps on SO... Happy Coding!

Comment: Lol I clicked too quick. Voted now.
Getting rid of the CDATA is just an added bonus. This works perfectly on our latest "document" ... now to see if I can get them all at once!
Thanks again!